# Python Selenium change url

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/Q7ckEKB0/#detalji")

print (driver.current_url)
```

I have list of links:

http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/ll33wwis/#detalji
http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/zLgwjGzm/#detalji

...

What's the best way of scrape data from all this links(using a loop?), in this program?
Please suggest me some example or documentation.

Comment: Have you looked at BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code, Here I am unable to test(or fetch data)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


class ReadBooksInfo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        # self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def read_HTML(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        html = self.driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        print(soup)
        # check for your expected tag here,
        rows = soup.find_all('tr')
        print(rows)


test = ReadBooksInfo()

urls = ["http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/Q7ckEKB0/#detalji",
        "http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/ll33wwis/#detalji",
        "http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/zLgwjGzm/#detalji"]
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    print(str(i) + "::" + url)
    test.read_HTML(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used urllib2 and BeautifulSoup. But without Selenium. Look at my code on Github. Code is not ideal and perfect, but I scrapped needed data.
[Github repo](https://github.com/devlat/tatparser)